# Create procedure within cursor for insert, select, update and delete

Tags: sql-server, insert, cursor, sql-delete, procedure

I have one question and I hope you can help me.
I want to create procedure within cursor for insert, select, update and delete.
I create select syntax and what is do for me?
I define this for user to run select after this cursor to show their results :

```
DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR GLOBAL
FOR
     SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
OPEN TableCursor
DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Schema NVARCHAR(50)
FETCH NEXT 
FROM TableCursor 
INTO @Schema,@Name 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN   
      EXECUTE('         
               CREATE PROC USP_SEL_'+@Schema+'_'+@Name+'        
               AS       
               BEGIN            
                     SELECT *
                     FROM '+@Schema+'.'+@Name+'         
               END
             ')
      FETCH NEXT        
      FROM TableCursor      
      INTO @Schema,@Name 
END 
CLOSE TableCursor 
DEALLOCATE TableCursor
```

and user can write this code to run their result :

```
EXEC [dbo].[USP_SEL_Production_Product]
```

My question is what can I do for insert, update and delete for a user that they just write `EXEC` and see their results?

Comment: This has some smell of a really bad approach... What exactly are you trying to reach? Do you want to create on Stored Procedure for each Table in your database, just to do a simple SELECT * FROM Table? If so, this **is** a really bad approach. If your users really should query the db on their own, prepare them some nice VIEWs...

Comment: This is our homework but i think every second but i cant solve it.

Comment: Let's clear this problem for you. Look we assume that user's knowlege is weak than write every query that he/she wants. I just write a cursor within Stored Procedure  and into Stored Procedure i want do execute insert,delete,select and update and he/she just write one code to run his/her result

Comment: If your user's knowledge is so weak, you should never let them down to your database ;-) There must be some layers between them to avoid data damage... If you really want to create one SP for all CRUD actions for each table, you'll have to code them (and I will not do this for you...). Just two hints: right click the table in SSMS and then on "Create Script". Let SSMS prepare some examples for you. The rest you'll find in INFORMATION_SCHEMA...

Comment: It's just a training! I know it's wrong approach